# Java 8 - does it change where final String variables end up?

Tags: java-8, metaspace

I could not find this question, sorry if my search skills missed!

Prior to Java 8, I believed that declarations such as:

```
...
public final String someString = "Hi";
public final int someInt = 17;
```

would be better declared as:

```
...
public static final String someString = "Hi";
public static final int someInt = 17;
```

with post PermGen (now Metaspace) is there still a difference?  Does `-XX:+UseStringDeduplication` have any effect on this difference (for the Strings anyway)?

Answer (score 2):

The variable containing a reference to an object has no impact on the referenced object. It would be strange if it had, as there can be plenty of different variables having a reference to the same object.

In other words, I assume, you already know that all String literals with the same contents refer to the same object, so if you declare *both*,

```
public final String someString1 = "Hi";
public static final String someString2 = "Hi";
```

`someString1` and `someString2` refer to the same object. So if the declaration of the variable made a difference for the object, which one should be relevant here?

You can even use the same object without a variable at all, e.g.

```
System.out.println("Hi");
```

There is a much simpler reason to declare the variable `static`. It always has the same contents, so there is no reason to reserve memory *for each object* for it, just to always read the same reference from that constant. In fact, since such a declaration is a compile-time constant, it will not even be read at runtime.

Comment: Yes, I knew all this - I was never interested in declaring both.  You just start to address my question in your last paragraph - "no reason to reserve memory".  Does Java 8 (with Metaspace) treat the first (non-static) declaration differently that previous Java versions?

Comment: I don’t get you. A non-`static` field is an instance field, part of the object, or more precisely, instance fields are exactly what makes up the object’s memory, and objects are stored in the *heap* memory. There is nothing more ordinary than a non-`static` field. And the memory reserved for the field, is the memory to hold the *reference* to the string.

Comment: [Enter Socrates mode] . So then you think none of these values go into Metaspace?  Above you talk about 'hi' "without a variable at all".  Where do you think that goes?  Once you answer those two questions, you get to mine: does a simple final String get allocated to the same place or somewhere else?  Secondarily, what about 'int's?

Comment: *Again*, the type of the variable has no influence on how the `String` is stored. The variable only contains a *reference* to an object. When you just use the literal `"Hi"` within an expression, the reference will be on the operand stack during the operation. When you refer to the string via non-`static` field or array, the reference will be in the ordinary heap, when the variable is `static`, the reference might be in the metaspace. Whether the variable is `final`, has no influence on the storage at all.There can be several references in different memory regions pointing to the same `String`

Comment: String literals haven't been in Perm Gen (or Metaspace) since Java 6.

Comment: The Oracle/OpenJDK creates a special singleton object for all the static fields of a class. You can see this object in a heap dump. I imagine this is implementation dependant.

Comment: @PeterLawrey indeed, and starting with Java 7, update 6, `intern()` will not make a copy of the `String` anymore (as `offset` and `length` fields are gone) and starting with Java 9, the internal array will be a `byte[]` array), but that’s all independent to the modifiers of fields referring to these objects, and implementation dependent (so we’re talking about HotSpot/OpenJDK here)…

Comment: @Holger is the value array guaranteed to be `char[]`, I though it would only do this for Strings which are shorter with a `byte[]`

Comment: @PeterLawrey starting with Java 9, it’s always a `byte[]`, I suppose they didn't want to need a type cast here. But that array contains either, an iso-latin-1 or utf-16 encoded string. The type is encoded in an `int` field that contains either, one or two, which allows to replace a lot of conditionals with basic arithmetic, as this type value reflects how many bytes a character needs in the array. Or well, it could also be that it is <zero or one> and represents the shift amount for offset/length calculations, which boils down to the same. I'm too lazy to look up the source code right now.

Comment: @Holger the field you are talking about is called `coder` and it's a `byte`, and it's possible values are 0 (for Latin1) or 1 for UTF16. And you are right again, length si computed as `return value.length >> coder();`, which is pretty neat

Comment: @Holger btw that could have been an `int`, the runtime representation of `String` would occupy the same size, since objects are 8 bytes aligned and there is a gap big enough to fit an `int`. What I also like is that if you concat multiple Strings, the final coder is going to be `OR` between all others